# Wildfly Servlet Deployment Error

Tags: servlets, wildfly

I'm migrating from JBoss 4.0.4GA to WildFly 8.1.0. During deployment, I'm getting the following error:

```
server.default-host./.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT010009: Servlet VxmlServiceServlet of type class com.nexge.commgenie.vxml.VxmlServiceFC does not implement javax.servlet.Servlet
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.ServletInfo.<init>(ServletInfo.java:99)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:620)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.start(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:245)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    ... 3 more
```

Could anyone please advise on what the issue is?

Thanks & regards, Shankar

Comment: I'm not sure what I did to truncate the beginning of the question, but it should be "HI im moving jboss 4.0.4.GA..."

Comment: Do you have `com.nexge.commgenie.vxml.VxmlServiceFC` in your web.xml declared as a servlet?

Comment: thanks for ur reply Mr James R. Perkins . i was declared in web.xml as below <servlet>
    <servlet-name>
    VxmlServiceServlet
  </servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
    com.nexge.commgenie.vxml.VxmlServiceFC
  </servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>VxmlServiceServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/VxmlServletFC</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>                                                                         OR I need to configure anything in wildfly server to deploy servlet program?

Comment: can you provide snippet?

Answer (score 1):

The error pretty much states exactly what the issue is. You have a servlet defined that doesn't extend `javax.servlet.Servlet`. If for whatever reason it is extending `javax.servlet.Servlet` then the likely issue is you're including some library in your deployment that contains a `javax.servlet.Servlet`.

Comment: ok thanks Mr james perkins. iwas wrongly added library in wildfly. now its working fine. how can i add my external api jars in wildlfy ? pls help me

Comment: Have a look at how to install a JDBC module http://wildfly.org/news/2014/02/06/GlassFish-to-WildFly-migration/#_jdbc_driver. Installing other modules is the same. Have a look at class loading docs, https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly, to see how to add them as dependencies.